# Inner joining three tables from the results of another query

Tags: sqlite, android-sqlite

So I know joining three tables has been asked and answer before but my situation and query is a bit different and the other solutions are not working for my needs.

So I have three tables, the first table does the primary sorting/filtering and does not have a primary key, the other two tables have most of the information in them and do use a Primary key ('Site').

I would like to get a list of Sites from the first table and then inner join all three tables based on the results.

I can do this in Python using a `for` loop but I imagine that there is a better / more succinct way of doing this.

Here is the python code:

```
q1 = "Select * from Drive where Origin='Seattle,WA' and Hour<3"
q2 = "Select * from Weather Inner Join Site On Weather.Site = Site.Site where Weather.Site='%s'"

for line in conn.execute(q1): # This gets all the Sites from the first table
    print(line)  # This prints the first table results
    print(conn.execute(q2 % line[0]).fetchone()) # This does the Join for the other two tables and prints the results from the two tables
```

This does work and I could use this in my application, but this feels brute force-ish and I'm sure there is another/better way.

Where I am running into issues is returning every column from all three tables with a where clause in the first query.

And as a follow up question say I wanted to put another 'Where Clause' on the Site table?

Something like:

```
q2 = "Select * from Site where Site.HasWater=1 Inner Join Weather On Site.Site = Weather.Site where Weather.Site='%s'"
```

Any help is always appreciated, thank you.

**Updated with relevant Schema**

3 Databases - Drive, Weather, Site

```
Drive - Site, Origin, Hour, Drive
Site - Site, LatLong, HasWater, etc. and about 15 other columns
Weather - Site, RainFall, etc. and 10 other columns
```

Site is the primary key in the tables: Site and Weather - but it is not the primary key in Drive because the Site column does not contain unique information where as it does in tables Weather and Site.

For example this is what the Drive Table looks like

```
Site  | Origin | Hour | Drive
Site 1, City 1,   2,    02:30:30
Site 1, City 2,   4,    04:45:57
Site 1, City 3,   1,    01:19:22
Site 2, City 1,   0,    00:56:34
Site 2, City 2,   1,    01:38:06
Site 2, City 3,   2,    02:23:41
```

So the first query is to narrow down the number of sites by Origin and Hour - and then the second query is to get all the information for each of the sites.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Can you add the schema for the relevant tables to the question.

Comment: updated with more info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the following may be along the lines of what you are looking for

```
SELECT drive.site, drive.origin, drive.hour, drive.drive, latlong, haswater, rainfall 
FROM drive
    JOIN weather ON weather.site = drive.site
    JOIN site ON site.site = drive.site
WHERE drive.hour < 3 AND site.haswater > 0
;
```

- Note additional WHERE clause added

The above is based upon the following being used to populate the tables :-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS drive;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS site;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS weather;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS drive (site TEXT, origin TEXT, hour INTEGER, drive TEXT);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS site (site TEXT PRIMARY KEY, latlong REAL, haswater INTEGER);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS weather (site TEXT PRIMARY KEY, rainfall REAL);
INSERT INTO drive VALUES 
    ('Site 1', 'City 1',   2,    '02:30:30'),
    ('Site 1', 'City 2',   4,    '04:45:57'),
    ('Site 1', 'City 3',   1,    '01:19:22'),
    ('Site 2', 'City 1',   0,    '00:56:34'),
    ('Site 2', 'City 2',   1,    '01:38:06'),
    ('Site 2', 'City 3',   2,    '02:23:41')
;
INSERT INTO site VALUES ('Site 1',10.5,1),('Site 2', 65.5,0);
INSERT INTO weather VALUES('Site 1', 23.45),('Site 2',12.6);
```

The results would be  :-

[image]

or without the additional WHERE clause (i.e. no `AND site.haswater = 1`)

[image]

Comment: yup that is perfectly what I needed - thank you very much.